# How to remake bidirectional mappings when deserializing JSON using Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, entity-relationship

I have the following entities:

```
public class OrderEntity {

    private long id;
    /// fields
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_entity_id")
    private List<BusinessCartEntity> businessCart = new ArrayList<>();

}

public class BusinessCartEntity {

    private long id;
    //fields
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonExclude
    private OrderEntity orderEntity;

}
```

I am using Gson to serialize them into JSON and then be able to restore them later.
For serializing I just ignored the relation to the parent entity to avoid StackOverFlow exception.
The problem rises when I want to deserialize them. Of course the relationships are not created, and the OrderEntity of a BusinessCartEntity will be null and will have to be manually created, which is hard to maintain.
Is there a way to tell Gson to set the value of orderEntity to the parent entity? Or to save a value for orderEntity when serializing and then correctly deserialize?

I'm using Gson to deserialize because I used it to serialize the objects, but I am open to other libraries, too. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@JsonIdentityInfo` with both classes

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class OrderEntity {...}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class BusinessCartEntity {...}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because it implies that I have to serialize/deserialize BusinessCartEntity, which is an element from the list.